$G$ is a finite, simple group of order greater than $60$, $G$ has no proper subgroup of index less than or equal to $5$.
Let $G$ be a finite, simple group of order greater than $60$. Then $G$ has no proper subgroup of index less than or equal to $5$.

Toward a contradiction, suppose $G$ had $H \leq G$ proper with $|G:H| = k$ for $k \leq 5$. Now, $G$ acts transitively on the left cosets of $H$ by left multiplication, inducing hom. $\varphi: G \to S_k$. By First Iso. Thm.
$$G / \ker \varphi \cong \varphi(G) \leq S_k$$
By simplicity, $\ker \varphi =1$ or $\ker \varphi = G$ and so $\ker \varphi = 1$, hence $G \cong \varphi(G)$. As $|\varphi(G)| > 60$, this forces $k \not\leq 4$ and so $k =5$. But this means $\varphi(G)$ contains an odd permutation and so $|\varphi(G): \varphi(G) \cap A_5| = 2$. But then $\varphi(G) \cap A_5 \trianglelefteq \varphi(G)$ and by simplicity again, $\varphi(G) \cap A_5 = 1$ or $\varphi(G) \cap A_5 = \varphi(G)$. If the latter, then $\varphi(G) \leq A_5$, a contradiction because $\varphi(G)$ has more than $60$ elements. So $\varphi(G) \cap A_5 = 1$, but I cannot derive a contradiction from this and I want to.
Something about this seems off because if $\varphi(G)$ has more than $60$ elements, then $|\varphi(G)|$ must still divide $120$ but that wouldn't be possible. So I am in doubt about the step where I assert $k \not\leq 4$.
The post here says that it's "easy to see" that if $|G|>2$, then $H \leq A_k$ but it's not clear to me why this is the case

For any subgroup $H$ of $S_k,$ $H\cap A_k$ is a normal subgroup of $H.$ This is easy to show. So for $H$ simple, either $H\subseteq A_k,$ which isn't possible here,  or every element $h\in H$ must satisfy $h^2=1,$ since $h^2\in A_k\cap H.$ But any group where every element is of order $1$ or $2$ is commutative, and the only simple such groups are $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ and the trivial group.

So  a simple subgroup of $S_k$ must either be a subgroup of $A_k$ or a cyclic group of order $2.$

There's no subgroup of $S_5$ of order greater than $60.$ (Other than $S_5$ itself. )

If $\phi(G)\cap A_5=1$, then as you mentioned $2=|\phi(G):\phi(G)\cap A_5|=|\phi(G)|$, which is a contradiction.
